# How to explicitely pass self as a super class to a method and being called back instead of subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, subclass, overloading

I have 3 classes

One base class : `MyBaseClass`

That implements a method :

```
- (void) aSuperMethod {
    [[UtilClass sharedUtil] doThisAndSendAnswerToMe:self]
}

- (void) answerReader:(bla bla)someParams {}
```

One subclass of MyBaseClass : `MySubClass`

That also implements these kind of methods :

```
- (void) anotherMethod {
    [[UtilClass sharedUtil] doThisAndSendAnswerToMe:self]
    [self aSuperMethod];
}

- (void) answerReader:(bla bla)someParams {}
```

And of course a utility class : `UtilClass`

That implements this kind of method :

```
- (void) doThisAndSendAnswerToMe:(id)listener {
    do some stuff
    [listener answerReader:someAnswerParams];
}
```

In debug mode, of course, the listener received in both calls by the doThisAndSendAnswerToMe method is of MySubClass class.

How may I do to point either on MySubClass or MyBaseClass depending on the call origin ?

Comment: What do you mean by "depending on the call origin"? When I first read this, I thought you meant depending on the class of the object, but that should already work, since the method call `answerReader:` will dispatch based on the class of the object.

Comment: ...You don't want the listener to receive the calls to run `answerReader:`? Or am I misunderstanding you? You have the line `[self.listener answerReader:someAnswerParams];`...

Comment: @gaige:I've made some edits to be more clear. I mean by "the call origin" the method and class type from wich the call was initiated. But the class of the object is MySubClass in both cases.

Comment: @David:ooops, "self." was a mistake. I made some edit to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The subclass's method implementation always overrides the superclass implementation.

One solution is to use a different method name in the superclass and the subclass, and pass the name of the callback method to UtilClass. UtilClass then uses -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] to call that method.

```
-(void)baseClassAnswerReader:(id)someAnswerParams { ... }
[[UtilClass sharedUtil] doSomethingAndSendAnswerToMe:self 
                                            selector:@selector(baseClassAnswerReader:)];
```

Another solution is to pass a completion block object to UtilClass. UtilClass then calls the block object when it is done.

```
[[UtilClass sharedUtil] doSomethingWithCompletionBlock:^(id someAnswerParams){ ... }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You use an instance of the base class if you want to use the base class, and you use an instance of the subclass if you want to use the subclass.

If you don't want the subclass method to override the superclass one, then make it a different method instead of overriding.